# Fallback for css-vars

Tags: javascript, css

I want to use CSS vars the first time and am doing that

```
#circle_1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: var(--size_1);
  height: var(--size_1);
}
```

and fill it with JS like so

```
var input_1 = document.querySelector("#groesse_1");
var circle_1 = document.querySelector("#circle_1");
input_1.addEventListener("change", function() {
  circle_1.style.setProperty("--size_1", input_1.value);
});
```

This works nice, but as long as the user doesn't add a value to input_1, the circles have a not defined size (which I tried to prevent by giving a default height/width in the CSS before I added the width: var(--size_1); thing)

How would I correctly add a default value to that element?

See here: https://codepen.io/daiaiai/pen/OQYwVW

Comment: did you [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)?

Comment: in addition to what @Kaiido said .. if you define twice the same property only the last one is considered and the other one ignored, so you cannot do this

Comment: You can use CSS Vars ponyfill https://codepen.io/jhildenbiddle/pen/ZxYJrR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS func [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) accepts two arguments: the `--var` custom property, and a fallback value.

So to properly fallback values you would do

```
selector {
  prop: 20px; /* for browser without support for variables */
  prop: var(--my_var, 20px); /* for browser with support for variables */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that when defining the variable, and you only supply `width` and `height` once:

```
#circle_1 {
  --size_1: 50px;
  width: var(--size_1);
  height: var(--size_1);
}
```

In your event handler, you'll also need to specify units unless you're expecting the user to enter them, e.g.:

```
circle_1.style.setProperty("--size_1", input_1.value + "px");
// -------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

...or similar.

More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

Live Example:

```js
var input_1 = document.querySelector("#groesse_1");
var circle_1 = document.querySelector("#circle_1");
input_1.addEventListener("change", function() {
  circle_1.style.setProperty("--size_1", input_1.value + "px");
});
```

```css
#circle_1 {
  --size_1: 50px;
  width: var(--size_1);
  height: var(--size_1);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input id="groesse_1" type="text">
<div id="circle_1"></div>
```

Comment: No that's not the place to do it, if user inputs `'foo-bar'`, then it will fail too, and your workaround won't work either.

Comment: @Kaiido: Garbage in, garbage out. Validating user input isn't the question.

Comment: Well when the question asks for a fallback, validation is the first step of the question.

Comment: @Kaiido: I don't see anything about validation in the question. As far as I can tell, it's purely about defining an initial size.

Comment: I know that's not part of the stackoverflow netiquette, but you helped me both very much and @T.J.Crowder s answer is what I looked forward to whilst both of you gave even more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a fallback default value

```
#circle_1 {
  width: var(--size_1, 30px);
  height: var(--size_1, 30px);
}
```

So this way the default value its `30px` but if `--size_1` its not empty it will override the `30px`

If you want to know more here [vars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) on MDN

Here is your updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQJXpw) with a fallback